# change value select box base on another select box

Tags: javascript

I have two select box like this example:

```
    <select name="head" id="head">
    <option value="0">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    </select>
```

And Array select box:

```
    <select name="body[]">
    <option value="0">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    </select>
```

How to change selected values in array select box (name="body[]") base on first select box (name="head") using javascript function?

And if I choose different value in any of array select box (name="body[]"), the selected value in first select box (name="head") has change to `<option value="0">Choose</option>`?

Comment: You bind event handlers to the select elements and create the `option` elements dynamically, based on the selected value (at least that's my understanding of what you are trying to do). Is there anything in particular you are having problems with?

Comment: add event on first select box as "onchange" call a javascript function and bases on this change the value of second box.  if not clear feel free to ask.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple script:

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#head').on({
            change: function(){ $('select[name^="body"]').val(this.value)}
        });
        $('select[name^="body"]').on({
            change: function(){$('#head').val(0)}
        });
    })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

bind the `change` event on the first select, then on the callback function modify the other select by adding new options.

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/orlando/SJEGX/

Comment: I think this just solve the first problem (binding) but he want to put the second one as selected as well not just changing the text

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <select name="head" id="head" onchange="$('#body').val(this.value);">
    <option value="0">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
<select name="body[]" id="body" onchange="$('#head').val(0);">
    <option value="0">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not to change only the value of the select, but to really select an option

(Add the id to body)

```
<select name="head" id="head">
  <option value="0">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select name="body[]" id="body">
  <option value="0">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

The JS

```
$("#head").change(function(){
  $("#body option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").prop('selected',true); 
});

$("#body").change(function(){
  $("#head option[value='0']").prop('selected',true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WZMCA/